# Angular dynamic ngProjectAs value

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular11, ng-template, ng-content

Is it possible top ngProjectAs value?
I want to have different projected content depending on a feature flag.

I have tried

```
<ng-container [ngProjectAs]="someBoolean ? 'filter2' : 'filter'">
```

and

```
<ng-container ngProjectAs="{{someBoolean ? 'filter2' : 'filter'}}">
```

Neither seem to work.

I tried having just "filter" but it seems having 2 of:

```
 <ng-content select="filter"></ng-content>
```

on the same page causes issues, even when one is wrapped in an ngIf.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to create an ng-template:

```
<ng-template #newFilterTemplate>
  <ng-content select="filter"></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

Because although you cannot use more than one ng-content with the same 'select' value, you can use multiple template outlets:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="newFilterTemplate"></ng-container>
```